# How to fix misconfigured grub

Tags: grub

So I wanted to install the nvidia properiatory drivers. So I blacklisted nouveau in modeprobe.d and edited /etc/sysconfig/grub to append rd.driver.balcklist=nouveau to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX and then ran grub2-mkconfig and did  not add -o and the boot directiory path so my grub config and when I reboot I am greeted with the grub commandline. I have chrooted into fedora and mounted the boot partition and ran grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg which is the path to the wifi boot directory. However it returns an error
'''rm :- unable to remove grub.cfg.new read only filesystem'''

Edit :- I fixed the issue by doing a chroot and mounting the boot partition as rw by first unmountinf the boot partition and running sudo mount -o remount,rw partition dir
Replace partition with the boot partition and replace dir with the directory where the  boot partition is supposed to be mounted. Then I ran grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg which regenerates the grub.cfg. The path is for UEFA systems if you have a bios system and/or you or an another distro leaving fedora the path will be different. Thank you @Madhubala . He suggested that the boot partition might be corrupted which is not true but to fix the boot partition he suggested mounting the partition as re which I did and I was able to regenerate the grub.cfg

Comment: I think your filesystem is corrupted : Run fsck ; use repair filesystem from gnome disk ; try remounting -rw access

Comment: It is not corrupted all the files are intact. Also I just did what you said by mounting the system as rw in the chroot and regenerates the grub.cfg and my system works. Thanks for the advice @Madhubala . I will write it as the solution